# Salesforce Apex Regex - @metion

Tags: regex, triggers, salesforce, apex

Keep getting no match on my regex don't know what went wrong.

```
String myString = 'test @abcd efg done'
Pattern p = Pattern.compile('@(\\w+)\\s(\\w+)');
Matcher pm = p.matcher(myString);
pm.group(); //getting no match error
```

Expecting first group to be abcd and second group to be efg.
Any idea on what is wrong with my regex?

Any help would be nice.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your regex is fine. The pitfall here is you need to use matcher.find() method before calling matcher.group(). So this works fine

```
String myString = 'test @abcd efg done';
Pattern p = Pattern.compile('@(\\w+)\\s(\\w+)');
Matcher pm = p.matcher(myString);
if(pm.find()) {
   System.debug(pm.group(1));
}
```